# ImportError: No module named rospy

Tags: rospy, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I roslaunch my node, the error I receive is

```
ImportError: No module named rospy
```

But when I open up the python environment and run `import rospy`, it imports successfully and I can access `rospy.__file__`, which returns

```
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.pyc
```

which is on my PYTHONPATH:

```
declare -x PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/<user>/indigo_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
```

I do have a custom installation of Python that seems to have messed up some catkin_pkg installation, which is why it's had to be appended to the path. When I remove it to run roslaunch as a debug, I just get the same error.

Running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Raspberry Pi, if that helps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223601/importerror:-no-module-named-rospy/) by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-01-08**:
Did you check PYTHONPATH in os.environ? What version of the python interpreter is started by roslaunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I worked out what the problem was.

I wanted access to the Raspberry Pi GPIO ports, so I had used `launch-prefix="sudo"` in my launch file. What this meant was that the file was launched in the root workspace which wasn't set up to use ROS. There is [apparently a workaround](http://answers.ros.org/question/165246/launch-node-with-root-permissions/) that I wasn't able to get to work.

So my problem was solved by removing that from the launch file.

In case anybody finds this on google, I can use the GPIO ports in a ROS node by running [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/). Some googling will produce an example script but this is either out-of-date or wrong - use the examples on the site.

---

Originally posted by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) with karma: 153 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2016-03-16**:
The pigpio library really made my day! It's working beautifully and I can even control the raspberry gpio pins from a remote machine. (Ubuntu on both machines, ROS running either on both of them or the remote machine only, no "sudo node" involved.)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those who still want to run a node as root despite the GPiO workaround hereabove, you must preserve the right environment variable: `launch-prefix="sudo -E PYTHONPATH=$(env PYTHONPATH)"`

---

Originally posted by [Yoan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29527/yoan/) with karma: 31 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35695/bjajo/) on 2020-11-25**:
I love you, thank you sooooo much!! :)